# .NET based applications will not launch

Tags: .net, application

We have a .NET 3.5 application that we've been using for about three years with no major issues and since yesterday it does not launch at all.

The application hangs.  It first starts three processes, all of them taking 116KB of memory and nothing more happens... they cannot be stopped via Task Manager, another launch of executable starts another (but only one) process with the same memory usage.

We've already contacted the company that wrote the software and they're aware of that, they found out that it only applies to Windows 7, it's probably not framework-dependent (since they also have older version of this software based on .NET 2.0 and they've received signals from other clients using it with same symptoms).

We would like to help solving the issue asap, because the software is crucial to us and we're wondering whether or not someone else encountered the same or similar issues and have any information leading towards the solution?

Summary:

- it uses .NET 2.0 or 3.5 depending on software version (and the company confirmed it happens to all versions)
- it uses Crystal Reports (9.0 for older versions, 13.0.X for newer)
- the issue only happens on Windows 7 (x64 probably, but cannot confirm that)
- the process (or 3 processes for first launch) are started with memory consumption between 112K and 116K, nothing happens, while moving the cursor over the screen it shows "waiting cursor"
- event log shows nothing, there's no message or anything pointing to the problem

Also already tried:

- re-installing the software does not solve the issue
- Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool does not solve the issue
- re-installing CR does not solve the issue
- updating OS does not solve the issue

We'll appreciate any information of similar problems encountered, etc., maybe someone else has the same problem??

@EDIT
New information is that it's not a problem with Crystal Reports, since any .NET application won't launch (same behaviour) - even a simple app with only one form, no other controls, no additional code behaves the same way.

@EDIT2

Same situation has been reported on Windows 10 after the system has been updated yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it happens that Avast after being updated "did the trick" blocking .NET Framework from initializing the AppDomain.